# QML: redraw TableView when context menu shown

Tags: qt, contextmenu, tableview, qml, updating

I show context menu when user right clicks on row at TableView and select clicked item:

```
downloadContextMenu.popup()

tableView.selection.clear()
tableView.selection.select(row)
```

but TableView show selection only if I will move mouse to something else (i.e. button) after it. So, how to update TableView in this case?
downloadContextMenu is Menu

P.S. If I will do it by this:

```
tableView.selection.clear()
tableView.selection.select(row)

downloadContextMenu.popup()
```

I will have the same problem, but after next opening of context menu (open menu, then click outside to close it, then open again)

Comment: What do you try to do here? You clear selection and reselect a row again. What sense of that?

Comment: @folibis because I need to have only one row selected

Comment: What about `selectionMode: SelectionMode.SingleSelection`?

Comment: Ok, I will try (maybe it already set). But question not about it. TabView not redraws if opened context menu

Comment: May be you can attach some screenshot? Just because I have several TableView's in my current app. And I use context menus without problems. At least i see no strange behavior, different from usual Qt components.